# Why does the scale Velocity hook animate more than once in mobile browsers?

Tags: velocity.js

The `scale` Velocity hook animates as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but it seems to animate twice in mobile Firefox and mobile Chrome:

[Example `scale` animation](http://codepen.io/gomoto27/pen/zGKVXQ)

When `duration` is set to small values (try 1), the element scales once and the scaling is undone.

Why does this happen?

Comment: velocity.js mentions that [in Chrome on Android, it will ensure that the first value of `scale` is always 1](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/8be6219de47c999c2556ddf138e66dd2c541f282/velocity.js#L1351).
Can anyone explain how it does that?

Comment: Probably the initial scale that codepen is using when in mobile is confusing Velocity. Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0z57r780/) like a charm

Comment: Although, you're right that the `scale` is being reset when `duration` is set below 17, which is just above the minimal time frame for 60 FPS. Perhaps this mechanism for mixing that issue is resetting it not correctly when the animation runs in a single frame.